# Change from MySQL Rand() to PHP random_int

Tags: php, mysql, random

We are creating a Random Number Game. We are currently using MySQL Rand() function in the below statement:

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
$row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid FROM ResultPackage 
    where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}'
    and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$this->curResultId = $row['resultid'];
}
```

We need to change this to PHP function Random_Int. Please can someone suggest a way of doing this by altering the above code. The random number still needs to be within a certain range as you can see from the WHERE criteria in the SQL statement.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting?

Comment: What's wrong with the current method?

Comment: The current method isn't actually random. "RAND() is not meant to be a perfect random generator. It is a fast way to generate random numbers on demand that is portable between platforms for the same MySQL version." From our research we've found Random_int to be a better method

Answer (score 0):

I am testing this code:

```
private function doPreEventStart($user) {
    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid as MaxResult FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        ORDER BY resultid desc LIMIT 1");
    $this->MaxResult = $row['MaxResult'];


    $row = db_fetch_item("SELECT resultid as MinResult FROM ResultPackage 
        where ResultPackage.slotid like '%{$this->curSlotId}'
        and ResultPackage.PackageID like '%{$user->packageid}%'
        ORDER BY resultid asc LIMIT 1");
    $this->MinResult = $row['MinResult'];

    $this->curResultId = int rand ( int $MinResult , int $MaxResult )
    }
```